# WPF DataGrid.SelectedItem assignment not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid, and the DG's `ItemsSource` is set when the user selects a Dictionary from a bunch of options.

I added a column of CheckBoxes to the DG and set it up so that only 1 row can have `IsChecked = true` at a time. When the user "checks" one of the boxes, the `Checked` event handler cycles through all the rows and sets `IsChecked = false` to each row's CheckBox except the `SelectedItem`, leaving only the row the user selected as `IsChecked = true`. This works fine when a CheckBox is `Checked` by the user.

But this CheckBox column is not "bound" to any piece of data in the Dictionary. So when the user "selects" which Dictionary to bind the DG to, the "default" object in that Dictionary is not marked as "default." So I try to `.IsChecked = true` the correct row directly after the `ItemsSource` is set.

BUT the problem lies in the fact that my `Checked` event handler `IsChecked = false`s everything but the `SelectedItem`, and then checks the `SelectedItem`.

When the user initially chooses which Dictionary to bind to the DG, the DG is filled (and checked) programmatically. THEREFOR the `SelectedItem` is always the first row. So, instead of `IsChecked = true`ing the ACTUAL default object, the DG `IsChecked = true`s the first row.

THE CLOSEST I GOT TO A SOLUTION:
I tried to modify the `Checked` event handler so that instead of getting the `SelectedItem`, it figures out which row is the "default" row, "unselects" all other rows, and ONLY "selects" this row. But for some reason this call doesn't work.

```
    dataGridSymbols.UnselectAll()
    dataGridSymbols.SelectedItem = row
```

Does anybody know what's wrong with this call? I know that I set the row correctly.. Maybe I need to set SelectedItem to the object, but how to I get to the object from the row?

Comment: You need to show some more code instead of trying to explain your code.

Comment: Thanks @DarylBehrens - I didn't think the code itself would help because my issue wasn't with syntax or anything, it was with general concepts. But thinking back, I guess posting the code would help more anyway since most people on here probably prefer to understand the concept via code instead of words anyway. So when I posted the answer, I posted it in code. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: No Problem. I would recommend you looking into MVVM pattern, as with WPF it is the preferred way to do things. The code you have here will be very hard to test, since it is in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Instead of using SelectedItem (which just returns whichever is highlighted) I finally found a way to use the row that the `Checked` event handler was called from. Here's the code that solved it, in case anybody wants to see.

```
    var cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    if (cell == null)
       return;

    // Keep getting parents until you get to the sender's row...
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(cell);
    while (parent != null && parent.GetType() != typeof(DataGridRow))
    {
       parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    }
    var row = parent as DataGridRow;
    if (row == null)
       return;

    var rowIndex = row.GetIndex();
```